# Utilizando Fragment, erro na Activity

Tags: android

estou criando um app e gostaria de saber onde estou errando, ta funcionando, mas na activity do fragment da erro.

```
package com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;


public class Nome_Pizzaria extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nome_pizzaria);

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));

    //TABS

    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = ab.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Pizzas");
    tab1.setTabListener(new NavegacaoTabs(new Fragment1()));
    ab.addTab(tab1);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = ab.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Favoritos");
    tab2.setTabListener(new NavegacaoTabs(new Fragment2()));
    ab.addTab(tab2);

}

private class NavegacaoTabs implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private Fragment frag;

    public NavegacaoTabs(Fragment frag){
        this.frag=frag;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("Script", "onTabReSelected(0");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fts.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag);
        fts.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fts.remove(frag);
        fts.commit();
    }
}
```

}

LOGCAT

```
04-11 12:39:04.186  16835-16835/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-11 12:39:04.205  16835-16835/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas, PID: 16835
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Nome_Pizzaria}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Nome_Pizzaria.onCreate(Nome_Pizzaria.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

[image: Sem ActionBar]

Sem ActionBar

Comment: Qual o erro que é apresentado no **LogCat**?

Comment: @Wakim coloquei na pergunta acima, pois não tinha espaço aqui.

Comment: Acho que você não deveria estar chamando o método `getActionBar`, porque já que está usando a biblioteca de suporte (`support-library-v4`), você deve usar os métodos de suporte. No seu caso seria `getSupportActionBar`, nos demais casos também: `getSupportFragmentManager`, `getSupportLoaderManager` e sempre que existir algo desse tipo.

Comment: Estou seguindo um tutorial, sendo que implementei da maneira que necessito, ele cria da mesma forma que está aí, mas no meu deu errado. Estou tentando modificar o que você falou.

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro que a sua Activity herde da ActionBarActivity e que o tema (styles/manifest) aplicado à ela use como parent a Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, por exemplo.
Se você quiser que apenas as tabs apareçam depois, use `getSupportActionBar().hide();` no onCreate da sua Activity ou no onCreateView dos seus Fragments.

Comment: Já deu certo. Descobri estudando e fuçando isso, mesmo assim muito obrigado pela dica, se não tivesse conseguido o seu exemplo foi o mesmo que usei e daria certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta o user Wakim já deu nos comentários, creio que você deva chamar getSupportActionbar() ao inves de getActionBar() por estar usando a Actionbar via support library.
Também acho que sua activity deve herdar ActionBarActivity, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Já fiz as alterações que vocês (@Wakim e @Informatheus) falaram, mas apresenta novos erros, para que eu possa implementar novos métodos.

Comment: Exponha aqui o logcat e todas as informações possíveis para te ajudarmos.

Comment: 04-11 14:30:43.516  28967-28967/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas, PID: 28967
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Nome_Pizzaria}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Nome_Pizzaria.onCreate(Nome_Pizzaria.java:23)

Comment: Acho que estou errando. Pois vi um pessoal falando que não é possível utilizar a TAB sem o action bar, será que é isso que estou errando? Pois como disse acima essa minha activity não tem Action Bar e sim uma ImageView no topo e abaixo dela as TAB.

Comment: Segundo seu logcat, você está tentando chamar o método setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean) em um objeto que é null na linha 22.
Sobre tabs, aconselho você dar uma boa lida nessa pagina: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: Descobri que esse erro aconteceu porque não coloquei isto aqui no android manifest:                               `<activity  android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:label="Pizzaria Napolitana"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
 </activity>`

Comment: Agora esta tudo certo entao?

Comment: Sim. Coloco resolvido? no título da pergunta?